# Combining mouse movement and click coordinates in order of which they happen into a var string for a get url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, get, mouseevent

Ok, I have some functions that fire on mouse movement and mouse clicks,

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
var pageCoords =e.pageX + "," + e.pageY;
prefix='&mousemove='
console.log(pageCoords);});
```

This print co-ordinates as they happen into the console.log like so:

```
(345,654)
(300,100)
```

My goal is to contruct a get query url in the order in which the clicks or movements happen, and then be sent to a db.

```
var= '&mousemove=(345,654),(300,100)&click=(300,100)&mousemove=(670,500)
```

Does any one have any ideas or experience with this kind a query build in pure Javascript? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
var pageCoords =e.pageX + "," + e.pageY;
prefix='&mousemove='
$("#get").html(pageCoords);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../your url',//url for send data
        data: { movements :$(this).html(pageCoords) },
        success: function(pageCoords)
        {
            $("#get").html(pageCoords);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="get"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks for your response vicky, the problem arrises when I have to stream multiple sources in to the get url and have them build in the correct chronological order i.e. click, Mouse movement and keystrokes.